# icCube - MDX - How can I create a filter in a Histogram using a button named "MONTH"

Tags: mdx, iccube

I need to create a filter between some buttons named and a histogram, so for example when I click on "Mois" the histogram will change automatically to show  us the Months.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure to understand your question. Each widgets has a set of events that can be generated (Event tab, 'on Row Click', 'on Cell Click ...).

Once the event has been defined with a name, 'histogram-click', in can be used mainly everywhere with @{eventName!defaultValue}. This will be replaced by icCube once the event changes. Check [here](http://www.iccube.com/livedemo/?ic3reportName=Actions%20(Events)) for a little more documentation.

Also, in Configuration/Report Javascript you can add some code that is called on event generation for more dynamic behavior (e.g. using jquery to change the page).

hope it helps

Comment: Thank you. At first the histogram shows the years on rows, I want when I click on the button, it shows me the months (Children), but I didn't find any solution for this because when I select months from the Time dimension, it gives me a list of all Months but I want just a button named "Months" to filter the histogram. (So The problem it to apply the child navigation by button, not by click on the histogram)

Comment: Sorry I don't get it, you want the navigation to use the button selection ?

Comment: Ok, There is a navigation strategy in the histogram named 'Children' for example to pass from years to months when i click on it. Ok, i want to apply this strategy using buttons, button named years and the second named months, the third named week , when i click on the botton months the histogram change to show me the months of the sales. Thank you for your Help.

Comment: I'd use the event in something like http://www.iccube.com/livedemo/?ic3reportName=Drilldown%20MDX . Not sure is currently supported to have events in the strategy.

Comment: Yes this trategy is work fine in my report but i want to apply it using buttons

Comment: I add a Picture to Explain more what i want.

Comment: You've to use the event in the MDX query for the axis (each button define one of the axis version)

Comment: Create a Actions/Buttons and fire this event with the value you're expecting

Comment: Thank you for your help , i found a solution for this , i'm just apply this : NON EMPTY{  Order( { @{datevente![Time].[Time].[Année].allmembers - [Time].[Time].[all]}},
                   [Measures].[Date_Construction_Produit], BASC) } ON ROWS ( To eliminate the second [all-M] )

Comment: You can create an [Empty Set] in your schema script so you can reuse it, it will be a bit shorter